# Is it possible to notification to specific connectionId in aspnetboilerplate framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-page-application, aspnetboilerplate

i'm developing using the `AspNetBoilerplate` Framework version 2.3 SPA
.In order to send notification to specific user while logged in from another device, want to do this by `INotificationPublisher` to specific `ConnectionId` is it possible? Or we have to send to all `connectionIds`?
to clarify my problem:
I want to when for example John is logged in from PC and then logged in from another device, he receive an alert in pc like this "someone logged in from another device..."

Comment: (1) By `ConnectionId`, do you mean SignalR's `Context.ConnectionId`? (2) How would you get this `ConnectionId`?

Comment: 1: yes 2: I dont know, is it possible? Do you have any idea to in order to send login notification from another device?

Comment: Can you clarify your use case?

Comment: @aaron,  Question updated

Comment: Is your question then `How to notify all other SignalR connections of current user?`?

Comment: No we want to send notif to old one, not new logged in one user

Comment: You want to `notify all other SignalR connections of current user` from new connection, right?

Comment: I want to notify all other SignalR connections of current user from new connection, except last one

Comment: "except last one" — that's what `all other` means.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218473/discussion-between-omital-and-aaron).

Comment: On ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: Yes Asp.Net MVC5, SPA, Abp veersion  2.3

Comment: If you are calling from `AccountController.Login`, then you can send to all existing connections since the new login has not created a SignalR connection yet.